# How to optimize replacing a large amount of entries in strings?

Tags: java, string, optimization

I'm finding a method for replacing a String with a large amount of entries.

The entries' size can be 500~5000, most of them got different character length. No regex in entrys. Will not be changed.
The String's length can be 10~250. Contains Unicodes and each one is different.
This method will be called about 100 times per second. Each one is in Async.
Replacements must be in order, and base on last replaced.

So, the methods I have tried is

```java
public String method(String text) {
    String result = text; // "This is a text. aabbuisaufdsafdsaa."
    HashMap<String, String> map = getMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
        result = result.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    return result;
}
```

Extremely slow. avg 31000 ns with 1000 size entries.

And the method I'm currently using StringUtils (commons-lang3 version 3.12.0):

```java
private String[] searchList = null;
private String[] replacementList = null;

public String method(String text) {
    String result = text; // "This is a text. aabbuisaufdsafdsaa."
    result = StringUtils.replaceEachRepeatedly(result, getSearchList(), getReplacementList());
    return result;
}

// Same with #getReplacementList.
private String[] getSearchList() {
    // This will be init when this class loaded. I just paste it here.
    if (this.searchList == null) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = getMap();
        this.searchList = new String[map.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            this.searchList[index] = entry.getKey();
            index++;
        }
    }
    return this.searchList;
}
```

Faster 50%~70% than upper one. avg 11000 ns with 1000 size entries.

So I'm finding a better method, which can be more sophisticated. The only thing I need is faster.
If there is any ideas, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Since the data is big and speed critical, there is not a general way to solve it, you must to exploit all invariants as be possible (e.g. wich freq `getMap()` key/values change?) The diference taking in account some invariants could be a determining factor. Also, provide instances for objetive benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks for the question. the key/values will not change during running.

Comment: You say no regex, but why not?  It might well speed things up.

Comment: Then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentz-Walter_algorithm algorithms must be taken in account but also, any invariant about the input data is useful too.

Comment: How did you benchmark? IDE debug mode, HotSpot JVM fresh start, or after the code ran several times so it could be optimized by JIT compiler? Maybe take a look at GraalVM in native mode.

Comment: no regex is the entrys don't use regex, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The benchmark is the console data after the program runs for a period.

Comment: Input data is unique, doesn't have invariant.

Comment: The length of the text to be replaced (with 10 to 250 characters) seems relatively short compared to the size of your map which has 500 to 5000 entries. Are you replacing your input character by character? if so, you might want to iterate over parts of the string and not over your map.

Comment: As said the entrys and String contains Unicode. But each entry key/value length should larger than 3, however determined by the configuration users used.

Comment: I somehow doubt you did proper nanosecond resolution banchmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full implementation with >1300 replacements per second (on my machine with my random instances) assuming `getMap()` do not change:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    // 10k keys to search in
    final Map<String, String> map = IntStream
            .range(0, 10_000)
            .mapToObj(x -> randomWord())
            .distinct()
            .collect(toMap(x -> x, x -> randomWord()));

    final StringSearcher<String> s = StringSearcher
            .builder()
            .ignoreOverlaps()
            .addSearchStrings(map.keySet())
            .build();

    // bench 1000 times
    final int TIMES = 1000;
    long total_time = 0L;
    for(int j = 0; j < TIMES; j++) {

        // random big string 7k chars
        final String big = IntStream
                .range(0, 1_000)
                .mapToObj(x -> randomWord())
                .collect(joining());

        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // current index on the input string
        int i = 0;

        // output buffer, we will append text chunks
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        // for every key in the input string...
        for (Emit e : s.parseText(big)) {
            // if there are text between previous key and current
            if (e.getStart() > i)
                // copy to buffer
                output.append(big.subSequence(i, e.getStart() - 1));
            // instead copy the key we copy the value (replace)
            output.append(map.get(e.getSearchString()));

            // the new pending position is at the end of the key
            i = e.getEnd() + 1;
        }
        // if no more keys found may be text to copy to buffer
        if (i < big.length())
            output.append(big.subSequence(i, big.length() - 1));

        // here output contains the replaced string.

        total_time += System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    }

    System.out.printf("Avg time: %f secs%n", total_time / (1000.0 * TIMES));

}

private static String randomWord() {
    return Integer.toString(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1_000_000, 10_000_000));
}
```

with output

```
Avg time: 0,000768 secs
```

the Aho-Corasick-fast implementation used is [neo-search](https://github.com/neo-search/multiple-string-searcher):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neosearch.stringsearcher</groupId>
    <artifactId>multiple-string-searcher</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

the key length is 6/7 chars, the map contains 10k keys to search and the length text for search and replace is ~7k.

Using your parameters (5k keys in map and 250 bytes length):

```
Avg time: 0,000052 secs
```

that is, **>19k replacements per second**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm checking Aho-Corasick algorithm right now. Must take it in the program.

Comment: (My implementation is directly usable, simply add the dependency and use lines from `// current index` to `total_time += ...`)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I'm just trying to understand how this works.

Comment: Ok, I have added comments, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: I really appreciate it. It's really much faster. Very obvious on long strings. And thanks for the comments. But this will split some characters at the end, don't subSequence length - 1

Comment: There's a issue. e.x
"Aa" -> "Bb", "Bbc" -> "Cc" and input "cAac" it will return "cBbc", not "cCc"

Comment: @Rothes, the keys are not prioritized and the replacements are not accumulated, if you require that behavior you should implement your own Aho-Corasick algorithm (is not trivial) reseting the internal trie state. Anyway, in your question the keys are not sorted (the internal Map could follow any arbitrary order). I assumed then there is not an accumulated replacement. Modify the algorithm as I said it's not trivial but the approach is the same.

Comment: Anyway, since yours input string are tiny (max 250 chars), you can repeat the `parseText` every time from the `getStart` to the end (at `// the new pending position is at the end of the key`). But you should provide an order for your replacements (if not, the replace is not deterministic and have nonsense do it since I could set any arbitrary order).

Comment: Thank you very much for your introduction, I seem to have found a solution that suits me.